# configmaps "aws-auth" already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I'm creating three EKS clusters using [this](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest) module. Everything works fine, just that when I try to add the configmap to the clusters using `map_roles`, I face an issue.

My configuration looks like this which I have it within all three clusters

```
map_roles = [{
    rolearn   = "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_no}:role/argo-${var.environment}-${var.aws_region}"
    username  = "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
    groups    = ["system:bootstrappers","system:nodes"]
    },
    {
    rolearn   = "arn:aws:sts::${var.account_no}:assumed-role/${var.assumed_role_1}"
    username  = "admin"
    groups    = ["system:masters","system:nodes","system:bootstrappers"]
    },
    {
    rolearn  = "arn:aws:sts::${var.account_no}:assumed-role/${var.assumed_role_2}"
    username  = "admin"
    groups    = ["system:masters","system:nodes","system:bootstrappers"]
    }
]
```

The problem occurs while applying the template. It says

```
configmaps "aws-auth" already exists
```

When I studied the error further I realised that when applying the template, the module creates three configmap resources of the same name like these

```
 resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
   # ...
 }
 resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
   # ...
 }
 resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
   # ...
 }
```

This obviously is a problem. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: EKS module only creates one configmap so I am guessing you are trying to create the 3 clusters in the same TF file using the count on the module. the problem with that is you will need 3 kubernetes providers pointing to each cluster but not sure if that is doable with this module.

Comment: V18+ of that eks module no longer creates/manages the aws-auth configmap, or any kubernetes resource for that matter. The approach we're taking is to create the map once via resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth", and composing its contents from the ["system:bootstrappers", "system:nodes"] groups that would have been added for the worker nodes, and appending to that the role maps you need.

Answer (score 3):

I know that it's too late. But sharing a solution that I found.

We should use **kubernetes_config_map_v1_data** instead of ***kubernetes_config_map_v1***. This resource allows Terraform to manage data within a pre-existing ConfigMap.

Example,

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = {
    "mapRoles" = data.template_file.aws_auth_template.rendered
  }

  force = true
}



data "template_file" "aws_auth_template" {
    template = "${file("${path.module}/aws-auth-template.yml")}"
    vars = {
        cluster_admin_arn = "${local.accounts["${var.env}"].cluster_admin_arn}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The aws-auth configmap is created by EKS, when you create a managed node pool. It has the configuration required for nodes to register with the control plane. If you want to control the contents of the configmap with Terraform you have two options.

Either make sure you create the config map before the managed node pools resource. Or import the existing config map into the Terraform state manually.

Comment: I dodged this issue myself with some other method. However, if you think your answer is legitimate, it'd be nice if you break it down with more detials/steps.

Comment: How can aws-auth be created before managed node groups? When using the eks module, it handles creating the node groups, and all kubernetes_* resources are supposed to be created after eks cluster has been created.

Comment: Hm, I think the way do to this would be to separate eks and k8s resources in your terraform project, so that you can terraform apply them separately. After creating eks, you would import the generated aws-auth map, before applying the k8s resources. This separation of concerns is actually recommended as best practice by Hashicorp, since there are internal issues with properly handling dependencies and timing when this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I've now tested my solution, which expands on @pst's "import aws-auth" answer and looks like this: break up the `terraform apply` operation in your main eks project into 3 steps, which completely isolate the eks resources from the k8s resources, so that you may manage the `aws-auth` ConfigMap from terraform workflows.

1. `terraform apply -target=module.eks`

   - This creates just the eks cluster and anything else the module creates.
   - The eks module design now guarantees this will NOT include anything from the kubernetes provider.
2. `terraform import kubernetes_config_map.aws-auth kube-system/aws-auth`

   - This brings the aws-auth map, generated by the creation of the eks cluster in the previous step, into the remote terraform state.
   - This is only necessary when the map isn't already in the state, so we first check, with something like:

```
  if terraform state show kubernetes_config_map.aws-auth ; then
    echo "aws-auth ConfigMap already exists in Remote Terraform State."
  else
    echo "aws-auth ConfigMap does not exist in Remote Terraform State. Importing..."
    terraform import -var-file="${TFVARS_FILE}" kubernetes_config_map.aws-auth kube-system/aws-auth
  fi
```

3. `terraform apply`

   - This is a "normal" apply which acts exactly like before, but will have nothing to do for `module.eks`. Most importantly, this call will not encounter the "aws-auth ConfigMap already exists" error since terraform is aware of its existence, and instead the proposed plan will update `aws-auth` in place.

NB:

1. Using a Makefile to wrap your terraform workflows makes this simple to implement.
2. Using a monolithic root module with -target is a little ugly, and as your use of the kubernetes provider grows, it makes sense to break  out all the kubernetes terraform objects into a separate project. But the above gets the job done.
3. The separation of eks/k8s resources is best practice anyway, and is advised to prevent known race conditions between aws and k8s providers. Follow the trail from [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1280#issuecomment-1035464040) for details.